# Importing an excel header in R

Tags: r, import-from-excel

I want to import an excel file to R. The excel file already has an implemented header which contains important information, but this header is not imported to R. What I tried:

library(openxlsx)
read.xlsx #cuts off the header

converting to csv #cuts off the header

converting to pdf, from pdf to txt #cuts off the header

Am I missing an obvious solution? I don't need the data of the header in any specific format, as part of the dataframe or as an ugly string, just so that I can extract it, and that extraction has to happen within the R-environment (not manually in Excel).

Edit: I have tried to upload another simplified version of an excel file with header, and it also didn't work. It seems to be a problem of the header itself, not its content

[header of excel sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gw3sV.png)

Comment: Can you describe the header more? are there any special characters that is making read.xlsx skip them?

Comment: Maybe look into the `readxl` package - you could make multiple calls to `read_excel` with different ranges specified to get both the data and header imported

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will work:

```
x <- loadWorkbook("examplexl.xlsx")

sheet1 <- x$worksheets[[1]]

headers <- sheet1$headerFooter

> headers
$oddHeader
$oddHeader[[1]]
NULL

$oddHeader[[2]]
[1] "Center header"

$oddHeader[[3]]
[1] "Right header\nInfo"
```

My "examplexl.xlsx" looks like:

[image]